# how can I apply to old record when add new eav

Tags: eav-attributes

I want add object toggle switch by eav with default ON (value = 1).
In add new screen it will active but in edit screen it not (value = 0)
new record I create will be apply this, but old record can't.
how can I apply this for old record?

My code:

```
    public function apply()
{
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

    $eavSetup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'available_for_sale', [
        'type' => 'int',
        'label' => 'Available for sale',
        'input' => 'boolean',
        'default' => 1,
        'visible' => true,
        'used_in_product_listing' => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'group' => 'General',
        'sort_order' => 100
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Magento Mass Action. Select all products you want in product grid and select Update Attribute Action. Be sure your queue are working.

Another option is add a command in a module and do it programmaticaly. Each on a production collection (through the walk function if there are a lot), set your value, save your model and you are done.

Comment: tks for your advice...I'll try that.....